# How to let Xcode recognize GraphQL files?

Tags: xcode, format, graphql

When adding a `.grapghal` file -which contains a graph query- into my project in the Xcode, it displayed as:

[image]

As shown, it is not formatted/colored. In addition, if I try to select the query and reindent (<kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) nothing will happen.

Is there a way to let this type of files to be recognizable for Xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `.graphql` the file type isn't supported at the moment.
The Apollo team has an add-on for Xcode that you could use:
https://github.com/apollographql/xcode-graphql

Pull the repo and run `./setup.sh` bash script in the folder.

If you have the 8th version of Xcode, please follow Manual instructions for installation at [README file](https://github.com/apollographql/xcode-graphql#manual-installation).